# how to disable the default groups in azure API management via ARM template deployment

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-api-management, azure-rm-template

By default, the following 3 groups are created when Azure API management is deployed -

1. Administrators
2. Developers
3. Guests

Is there a way to not have these groups while deploying the API management via ARM template.

Answer (score 1):

APIM does not allow you to customize default service content at deployment time, and ARM templates do not allow deletion of resources as part of a deployment. So I think it's possible only with custom automation logic.